# Regression Relationship Between Fraction and Whole Number

Tags: regression, linear, poisson-regression, percentage, offset

I am trying to determine the best regression model to use to determine if there is a relationship between `clicks` (independent variable) (represented as a whole number) and `sql %` (`sql`/`sal`)(represented as fraction)(dependent variable).

Can any explanation of this data be valid if I were to run a linear regression on these two metrics (`clicks` and `sql %`)?

As I pointed out, `sql %` is the output of dividing `sql`/`sal`. Both `sql` and `sal` are represented in my table. Would using either metric in the regression act as a substitute for the dependent variable in the original regression I'm trying to run (`clicks`,`sql %`)?

I currently ran a linear regression on `clicks` and `sql %` and there is a R-Square of `0.018` which makes sense when looking at the plotted data points and clearly seeing that there is no linear fit.

**Data:**

```
date    sals    sql %   sqls    clicks
9/1/17  31      0.32    10      18
9/2/17  9       0.11    1       17
9/3/17  10      0       0       11
9/4/17  15      0       0       11
9/5/17  41      0.41    17      7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your variables $sqls$ and $sals$ both seem to be counts you could choose Poisson regression. The disadvantage of linear modelling of the $sql %$ is that it is bounded at zero and unity whereas linear regression gives predictions potentially outside that range. If you use Poisson regression you model $\log(sqls)$ as a function of $clicks$ using $\log(sals)$ as an offset. This gives the multiplicative effect of $clicks$ on $sqls$ by exponentiating the coefficient. There are many posts on this site going into more detail about Poisson regression. It is widely available in statistical software like Stata or R.